# The mean square of $d_k(n)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, complex-integration, divisor-sum, multiplicative-function

Let $d_2(n)=d(n)$ be the divisor function, and let $$d_k(n)=\sum_{d_1\cdots d_k= n}1=\sum_{m\cdot l= n}d_{k-1}(m).$$ Can anyone point me to a reference to the size of the error term when approximating
\[ \sum _{n\leq x}d_k(n)^2?\]
Since the Dirichlet series is $\zeta (s)^{k^2}f(s)$ for $f$ essentially bounded and holomorphic for $\sigma >1/2$ I think a Perron formula argument would give an error something like $x^{2/(4+k^2)}$, or perhaps a bit better with a result on moments of $\zeta (s)$.

Comment: the Dirichlet is not quite $\zeta (s)^{k^2}$ but $\zeta (s)^{k^2}G_k(s)$ where $G_k$ is analytic at least for $\Re s >1/2$ (eg $k=2, G_2=1/\zeta(2s)$) so one has to be careful

Comment: true, let me edit

Comment: Ivic and Titchmarsh discuss a bit this in the context of Omega theorems (chapter 9 - page 244 in Ivic where he uses Perron but in a limited way for his purposes, and chapter 8 in Titchmarsh which gives an approach based on Legendre polynomials) but not sure either has anything in your direction

Comment: many thanks for that Ivic reference (true he's not interested in power savings but the reference still helps me i think)

Comment: happy that Ivic proved helpful; also note that the traditional divisor problem $\Delta_m(x)=O(x^{\alpha_m+\epsilon})$ is generated by $\zeta^m$ after taking residues at $1$ so for $m=k^2$ there is a similarity between $\Delta_{k^2}(x)$ and your problem and there is really very little known about $\alpha_m$ for $m \ge 8$ or so- under Lindelof we have of course $\alpha_m \le 1/2$ and viceversa, but the best general result known is something like $\alpha_m \le \frac{m-1}{m+1}$ so i doubt that one can do better for your problem as of now at least

Comment: it's ok, i just needed any basic/auxillary result (just wanted a clean statement).  however i'm wondering about your comment: for $d_2(n)$ the error bound as you'll know obviously is a bit less than 1/3 (right?) but $d_2(n)^2$ has an error bound essentially $\ll \sqrt x$ (Ramanujan/Wilson)

Comment: The square behaves like $d_4$ so while for $d_4$ it is known $1/2$ and conjectured for $3/8$ for $d_2$ it is conjectured $1/4$ so it kind of makes sense what you say; not sure if there is a formal relation though as both bounds are for errors where we substract main terms

Comment: Consider Selberg-Delange method, which works even when $k$ is complex.

Answer (score 1):

For larger $k$, the best error term you can hope for has the form:

$$\sum_{n\leq x}d_k(n)^2 = R_k(x) + O_\epsilon\left(x^{\frac{k^2-a}{k^2}+\epsilon} \right) $$ where $$R_k(x)=\sum_{m\leq k^2} x C_{m}(\log x)^{m},$$ for some constants $C_m$, and where $a>0$ is a constant. In particular, proving this for $a=1$ should not be too difficult, but proving it for $a>5$ is beyond current methods (see also the best existing bounds for the related [Plitz Divisor Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Piltz_divisor_problem))

I don't know of a reference to this exact problem, but in Wilson's 1921 paper, [Proofs of Some Formulæ Enunciated by Ramanujan](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s2-21.1.235), he showed that for the [usual divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), $d(n)$,

$$\sum_{n\leq x}d(n)^r = L_r(x) + O_\epsilon\left(x^{\frac{2^r-1}{2^r+2}+\epsilon}\right)$$
where $L_r(x)$ takes a similar form to $R_k(x)$ above.

For smaller $k$ you can do better. Wilson in the same 1921 paper proved that for $k=2$, you have an error of the form $O_\epsilon\left(x^{\frac{1}{4}+\epsilon}\right)$.

Comment: thanks for the answer and links!